# If df records is in English move it to another column using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I had a list of Arabic and English elements, I transfer it into a dataframe BUT the issue is I have all values in One single column, I want to move the records that contains English words to another column:
so what I have now:

| COLUMN 1 |
| --- |
| هلا |
| السلام |
| WELCOMING |
| شي اخر |

THE OUTPUT THAT I WANT IS:

| COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 |
| --- | --- |
| هلا | welcoming |
| السلام | others eng. words |

hope its clear..

Comment: do you have only two languages ? arabic and english ?

Comment: Yes i just have these two

Answer (score 2):

You could go through the dataframe and use regex to see if the word is within the alphabet

```
reg = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]')

if reg.match(word):
    # Matches English
else:
    # Doesn't match English
```

or use [isAlpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
if word.encode().isalpha():
    # Matches English
else:
    # Doesn't match English
```

Depending on that, you could create a new dataframe and populate the appropriate columns.

Comment: how can i apply this with df column?

Comment: this is qute nice as it avoids external modules like `langdetect`.  You would put code inside the if statement to move to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each entry if the first character is part of ASCII. If so, move to new column.

Disclaimer: Only works if one language contains no ASCII at all and the second language only contains ASCII-Characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **langdetect** library along with the **pandas** library like (and it works for any language):

```
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect, DetectorFactory

# init seed
DetectorFactory.seed = 0

# read data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# filter data
df_ar = df.drop(df[(df['col_1'].apply(detect) != 'ar')].index).reset_index()
df_other_lang = df.drop(df[(df['col_1'].apply(detect) == 'ar')].index).reset_index()

# get the result
result = pd.concat([df_ar, df_other_lang], axis=1).drop('index', axis=1)

# testing .. 
print(result)
```

output :

-before :

```
       col_1
0        هلا
1      hello
2     السلام
3  WELCOMING
4      other
```

-after

```
    col_1      col_1
0     هلا      hello
1  السلام  WELCOMING
2     NaN      other
```

You can then rename the cols afterwards

Comment: i use jupyter and it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langdetect' "

Comment: obviously, you have to download the library, install it in python, using : `pip install langdetect` from your terminal, or in jupyter notebook in your first cell like : `!pip install langdetect`

Comment: i had this error Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/langdetect/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/langdetect/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping, i tired to downloaded it from anaconda prompt but failed!

Comment: try with these : https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/langdetect